# Finding the mean of two different 2x1 row-column groups for Data

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I am a bit new to Python. I am enumerating through a large list of data, as shown below, and would like to find the mean of every line.

```
for index, line in enumerate (data):
    #calculate the mean
```

However, the lines of this particular set of data are as such:

```
[array([[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10],
       [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]], dtype=float32)].
```

I would like to find the mean of both 2x1s separately, then obtain a list of those two averages.

Comment: would you like to post some code with the question ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  showing what you have tried and where you are stuck..

Comment: Hi, I edited the question - thanks for your input. I found a way to obtain the list that I'm looking for, but I don't know how to find the average of the two 2x1s posted above, as they are.

Comment: what you have is a list containg a list which contains two lists.  did you mean for this ? or do you mean this ?  `[[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10], [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to avoid tagging things that are irrelevant, netCDF in this case, as there are people who search the tags

Answer (score 1):

The question contains a `list of lists` which is inside a list.

So you just need to get rid of the outside list first (it has only one element). Then you can find the average (`mean`) of the other lists using the `statistics` module.

It will look like this:

```py
import statistics

# given data
x = [[[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10],
       [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]]]

x = x[0] # remove outer list

# elements via list comprehension (other methods too)
s0 = [a[0] for a in x]
s1 = [a[1] for a in x]

# print results
print(statistics.mean(s0))
print(statistics.mean(s1))
```

The result look like this:

```
1.81753965e-10
1.89993675e-10
```